# Notificação em Android não desaparece da barra de notificações

Tags: android, android-notification, notificação

Estou trabalhando com  notificações em `android`.

A notificação aparece quando é suposto e faz uma determinada questão ao utilizador, este por sua vez só tem de responder "sim" ou "não", através dos dois botões que essa mesma notificação disponibiliza.

Um dos problemas que me debato é que o utilizador quando clica em um dos botões, a notificação regista o que é suposto (a resposta do utilizador), mas a notificação permanece na barra de notificações.

O que eu pretendo é que, logo após registrar a ação do utilizador, que a notificação desapareça da barra de notificações.

Especifico a data e hora da notificação.

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, data % 100);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, ((data / 100) % 100) - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, data / 10000);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, horaFim);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutoFim);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        // Obtém um alarm manager
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // O id a ser usado no pending intent
        int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateNotificationReceiver.class);
        // Obtém o pending intent
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Crio a notificação com os respetivos botões

```
    public class CreateNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            int id = extras.getInt("id");

            Intent intentSIM = new Intent(context, SIMService.class);
            intentSIM.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));

            PendingIntent resultPendingSIM =
                    PendingIntent.getService(context,
                            0,
                            intentSIM,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                    );

            Intent intentNAO = new Intent(context, NAOService.class);
            intentNAO.putExtra("id", String.valueOf(id));

            PendingIntent resultPendingNAO =
                    PendingIntent.getService(context,
                            0,
                            intentNAO,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                    );

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle("Responde:")
                    .setContentText("Queres alomoçar?")
                    .setContentIntent(resultPendingSIM)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
            mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.outros);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.outros, "Sim", resultPendingSIM);
            mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.outros, "Não", resultPendingNAO);
            mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);


            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(1000);

            mNotificationManager.notify(id, mBuilder.build());

        }
    }

    public class SIMService extends IntentService {

        public TPCCriadoService() {
            super("name");
            System.out.println("estou no SIM");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("SIM");
        }
    }
```

Se me puderem dar umas dicas ficaria muito agradecida.

Comment: Disponibilize o código que se assemelha a situação que você descreveu acima, para que possamos ter um ponto de partida. Faça o tour do SOpt e entenda como se fazer uma pergunta para obter respostas rápidas.

Comment: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Bsalvo disponibilizei o código, obrigada pelo alerta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesses 2 serviços que você chama com os intents da notificação, tem que haver um método que limpe a notificação após receber o Action da mesma. Algo assim:

```
public void clearAllNotifications(Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```